# is $a \circ b \circ a=a$ when $[A,\circ]$ is a semi-group

Tags: semigroups

Let $[A,\circ]$ be a semi-group. Further $\forall a,b$ if $a \neq b$, then $a\circ b \neq b \circ a$. Now show that

$a\circ b\circ a=a$

My argument is as follows:

since in semi-group we have Associativity property,

So, we have $(a\circ b)\circ a=a \\ a\circ(b\circ a)=a$

So, seems like we have en identity element for this semi-group and that is $a\circ b=b\circ a$.

Hence, $a\circ b \circ a=a$

Am I correct in my argument?

Comment: How does $a\circ (b\circ a)=(a\circ b)\circ a$ imply that $a\circ b\circ a=a$?

Comment: By Associativity

Comment: How does associativity imply that $a\circ b\circ a=a$?

Comment: You assumed that $a \circ b \neq b \circ a$ and concluded that $a \circ b = b  \circ a$ satisfies something, so this cannot be correct.

Comment: So, how to proceed in this one.I am not getting any clue, other than what I posted, which came out to be wrong :/

Answer (score 1):

Let $a \in A$ and let $b = a^2$. Then $ab = ba$ and hence $b = a$, that is, $a^2 = a$. Thus your semigroup is a [band](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Band_(mathematics)) or, if you prefer, an idempotent semigroup. Now, consider $c = aba$. Then $ac = aaba = aba = c$ and $ca = abaa = aba = c$. Thus $ac = ca$, whence $a = c = aba$.